# How to show unit on bar chart range axis

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart

I am new in jasper report. I am trying to create a bar chart graph that display unit on range axis, just like attached picture. By default data value will be shown on Y axis without unit. Is it possible? I tried to use chart customizer but cannot find property that would help. Any help would be appreciate.

*bar chart with unit on range axis*
[image: bar chart with unit on range axis]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to convert number to percentage,

> edit the Chart Plot Properties -> Value Axis Tick Label Mask with
> `#%`.

Which will change the number to percentage (e.g. 0.1 -> 10%).
In addition, you can change '%' to 'cm', 'Mb' or something else for different unit.
[image: Chart value axis unit configuration]